# Circuit analysis using KVL

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

[image: I have done like this]
But, the answer is different. Given \$i=-8A\$ and \$v_0=48V\$. Can't understand where is my mistake. Please help.

Comment: Notice that \$Vo = -  i \times 6 \Omega\$  [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12+-+x*4+-+2*%28-x*6%29%2B4-x*6%3D0)

Comment: Notice that V0 is the negative of the voltage drop across that bottom resistor (with the current direction as defined).

Comment: @relayman357 that's right! Thank you.